# How do you get rid of this popup in Microsoft IME (Korean)?

Tags: windows-7, regional-settings, ime, korean

I don't know what this popup is called:

[image: Microsoft IME popup]

I had never seen it in Windows XP. I enabled Microsoft IME (Korean) in Windows 7, and now as I type each syllable appears *only* in this box (instead of the input area I'm focused on) until the syllable is deemed "complete". This all used to happen inline.

How can I restore the old behavior?

Comment: I assume it's part of the language bar? If you right cilck on it do you get a context menu

Comment: Yes, I looked at all of the settings, tabs, etc. and could not find a way to revert. I could have missed something, but it's hard to search for a solution because I don't know what to call it.